# Transiting through the UK both ways on a return journey

Tags: visas, uk, transit

I am a citizen of one of the countries for which travellers need a transit visa to pass through the UK.

The question is:

If you need a visa to transit through the UK, do you need ANOTHER transit visa for your return flight (if that also goes through the UK)?

Answer (score 4):

> A person will qualify for a multiple visitor in transit visa as long as their passport and visa for the country of destination are still valid for at least two months after the expiry of the multiple entry visa. This will allow the applicant to transit the UK any number of times within the period for which the visa is valid. The two month rule for the multiple entry visa is not compulsory for a single entry visa.

***Source*** : [UK Border Agency](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/sitecontent/documents/policyandlaw/modernised/visiting/transit-visitor.pdf?view=Binary), p.12

Comment: You could add a short summary of your quote, as such we do not know what part of the quote is valuable. And what 'multiple entry visa' does it refer to? a multiple entry transit visa, or another visa?

Comment: If you read the comment, it does mention Transit Visa. The source is mentioned. Read through the document for better understanding.

Comment: Once again, I think it could be made a little clearer. In the first sentence, there is 3 references to visas, the last one I cannot understand what it refers to. I think adding a short sentence BEFORE quoting would add some value, something like 'You can transit through UK up to 2 months after the expiry of some other visa'. My goal is not to annoy you, just to help improve your answer.